# How to create a window.location.replace() using sveltekit

Tags: javascript, svelte, browser-history, sveltekit

Is there a way to create `window.location.replace` in SvelteKit, like we can use `goto()`?

I want a way to not save the current URL in history. The current URL has query strings that change and the user cannot use the back button to go to the previous page. Instead, just go to the page with different query strings.

Edit: I am using `history.pushState()` and `history.replaceState()` to not save the URLs in history. I wish there was a built-in way in SvelteKit to do this.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `replace` does not navigate, so why not just use it?

Comment: replace completely reloads the page making a  few components useless.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was `history.replaceState`. There is no need for SvelteKit to have anything like that because it should not interact with its routing.

Answer (score 5):

There is a `replaceState` parameter on `goto` that may do what you're looking for.

```js
goto('/wherever', { replaceState: true });
```

Looks like the options passed to `goto` could be better documented, I'll see if I can fix that.

[Current docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto)

Comment: This is now documented: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto